# react-native-google-places-autocomplete not working when wrapping it with view

Tags: react-native, google-places-autocomplete

im pretty new to react-native, and facing right now with that problem:

google-places-autocomplete not working when wrapping it within a view (the scrolldown doesn't display), when i'm deleting the view it works..

console log doesn't display anything, the android emulator else.

help some1 ? thanks anyway :)

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import FormCity from '../components/FormCity';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';

const addFlightScreen = () => {

    const [destination,setDest] = useState("");

  return (
      <View>
          <FormCity onDest={setDest}/>
          <Text>Hello</Text> 
      </View>
  );
};

export default addFlightScreen;
```

and

```
import React from 'react'; import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

const FormCity = ({onDest}) => {

  return (
        <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
            placeholder='Enter Country, City (your destination)'
            minLength={2}
            autoFocus={false}
            returnKeyType={'default'}
            keyboardAppearance={'light'}
            listViewDisplayed='auto'
            fetchDetails={true}
            renderDescription={row => row.description}
            onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                onDest(data.description);
                console.log(data.description);
            }}
            getDefaultValue={ () => ''}
            query={{
                key: 'API_KEY',
                language: 'en',
                types: '(cities)'
            }}
            styles={{
                textInputContainer: {
                    width: '100%'
                },
                description: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                },
                predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                    color: '#1faadb'
                }

            }}
            
    />   ); };

export default FormCity;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

I wrapped the autocomplete component in a view with an absolute position and a height like below :

```
    <View style={styles.autoComplete}>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
      placeholder="Type a place"
      query={{key: config.GOOGLE_API_KEY}}
    />
  </View>
  <View style={styles.mapPreView}>{locationPreview}</View>
```

style :

```
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  autoComplete: {
    marginTop: 20,
    height: 200,
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 100,
  },
  mapPreView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
    marginTop: 80,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your use case. But I faced this issue and my solution was to put Places component in main view of page (flex:1 OR full height width) as its last child and make its position absolute. Because when you type in search, its height need to be increased dynamically. Try giving styles to your parent view.

Answer (score 2):

In your parent View add `flexGrow: 1`

```
return (
  <View style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <FormCity onDest={setDest}/>
      <Text>Hello</Text> 
  </View>
);
```